# Why is ranges::split_view not a Bidirectional Range?

Tags: c++, range-v3

I am using the cmcstl2 library with the C++ proposed Ranges with gcc 8

```
std::string text = "Let me split this into words";
std::string pattern = " ";
auto splitText = text | ranges::view::split(pattern) | 
        ranges::view::reverse;
```

But this does not work since the view is only a Forward Range not a Bidirectional Range which required by range (which is what I think is going on). Why? if

```
text | ranges::view::split(pattern)
```

outputs a view of subranges. Can't that view be reversed?

Also in cmcstl2 I must do the following to print it out.

```
for (auto x : splitText)
{
    for (auto m : x)
        std::cout << m;
    std::cout << " ";
}
```

But in range-v3/0.4.0 version I can do:

```
    for (auto x : splitText)
       std::cout << x << '\n';
```

Why? What is the type of x?

Comment: "*Can't that view be reversed?*" But you said it's a ForwardRange. By definition, a ForwardRange only goes in *one direction*. If it could go backwards, it would be Bidirectional.

Comment: Yes, but why? Why can't a view of subrange views (if that is what it is) be Bidirectional?

Comment: Why do you think it has anything to with being "a view of subrange views" instead of the fact that it's a string-splitting view and therefore only goes in one direction?

Comment: It's not that (arbitrary view of views) cannot be Bidirectional. Sure it can. It's that _specifically_ `split_view` is not Bidirectional (it's just a ForwardRange)

Comment: I am just trying to understand why split_view has this restriction.

Comment: Actually if the underlying view is bidirectional, split could return a bidirectional. It was summited as a bug https://github.com/ericniebler/stl2/issues/620

Answer (score 1):

The way it's been written only supports ForwardRange.

You can certainly try to make a BidirectionalRange version, although I suspect that is either hard or less general.

Consider how to specify all the options for `pattern` such that it can also match backwards.

Comment: After much thought, I see where you are coming from. When the view expression is evaluated during an assignment or range for, it must reverse first then evaluate the pattern and then create the subranges. It is hard to evaluate any size forward looking pattern going backwards. It seems easier if the pattern is only one character in length as in my example.

Comment: Like I posted above, this is now an issue on github. So maybe it is not impossible after all as long as the input range is Bidirectional.

Comment: @tcw321 I didn't say it was impossible, just that the *current implementation* only supports ForwardRange. At a guess, you issue will do better if it is accompanied by an implementation.

Comment: Sure I understand that the current implementation only supports ForwardRange. What I misunderstood from your answer that if I consider all options for pattern, it might not be possible to support anything other than ForwardRange. My question was really whether it was actually possible to support BidirectionalRange. I hope to prove this to myself by implementing it at some point.